OK to use dish detergent into toilet bowl?
I found a bottle of dish detergent from years ago. It appears discoloured. I checked online to see whether it works as toilet bowl cleaner. I found that it might help in unclogging toilets, but there is warning against using it regularly for toilets because it's bad for gaskets and seals. However, the warning often (not always) pertains to using dish detergent in the water reservoir tank. So it is unclear whether the warning applies to using dish detergent in the toilet bowl.
What do plumbers say about using dish detergent in the toilet bowl?

Not much use.   Dish detergent mainly dissolves oil.  Other stuff too but that's the key thing.  Toilet cleaners are thicker, contain stronger disinfectant, and bleach to remove rings and stains.   Using dish soap in the toilet will not clean it well and will create a lot of bubbles.

That's just expensive TSP with a wetting agent. Go nuts.

@jay613   I forget now which toilet/household cleaner it was, but the tv ad did have scrubbing bubbles.

@crip659  It was Dow Bathroom cleaner.  I tried it once and never got those bubbles to work... :-)...   Dow sold it was it was rebranded as "scrubbing bubbles".

@JACK  Never used them, but the commercial was cute.

Thanks jay613 and Mazura.  To jay613: even if it does a bit of good, I would find it preferable over just empty the bottle down the sewer outside. Any comment on the specific concern regarding vulnerability of seals/gaskets?

Not a plumber, but:
It will not 'harm' the toilet bowl. Toilet plumbing is the same thing as your kitchen sink plumbing (and guess where the dish washing detergent goes when you are finished). If your goal is to safely dispose of the contents, just pour it in the bowl and flush.
Whether it will do anything 'good' for your toilet bowl - not really. Dish detergent is mild, to not harm your hands. In toiled bowl you want to use bleach and such because of the bacteria. You can try cleaning with it (wear rubber gloves), but don't expect wonderful effects.

Thanks, Thomas.  That means that the vulnerable seals/gaskets do not occur along the egress pathway of the toilet bowl. Rather, they occur between the reservoir tank and the toilet bowl.  I don't intend to always use dish detergent.  I'll alternate between dish detergent and bleach or vinegar (which should not be combined, for safety reasons).  I won't combine dish detergent with either bleach or vinegar because I am unsure of the possibility of nullifying effects.
